# When you become a more conditioned athlete, how has your body changed?

Tags: muscle, endurance

A boxer gets tired out in 3 rounds at his current physical state and health.

He then trains in a way that would enable him to last a 12 round fight.

What exactly is happening to his body that will transform him from a 3 round fighter to a 12 round fighter?